# Controlar evento no campo?

Tags: java, swing, listener

Estou tentando tratar uma possível busca vazia, quando o usuário der <kbd>enter</kbd> em um campo sem digitar nada. Eu apliquei um evento de teclado, e todas vez que for pressionado enter, o campo realiza uma busca.

O problema, é que se a mensagem aparecer e clicar enter novamente, ele vai entrar em loop infinito, pois o campo possui  foco. Tem como desabilitar o evento ate a mensagem ser fechada ou algo do tipo ?

O que eu fiz:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Pesquisa extends JFrame {

    JTextField pesquisa = new JTextField();
    JLabel resultado = new JLabel();

    public Pesquisa() {
        setTitle("Teste !");
        add(tela());
        setSize(500, 350);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent tela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(pesquisa);
        painel.add(resultado);
        pesquisa.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 22));
        pesquisa.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)
                -> {
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher((KeyEvent e1)
                    -> {
                if (e1.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED && e1.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    String conteudo = pesquisa.getText();
                    if (!(conteudo.isEmpty())) {
                        resultado.setText("Resultado: " + conteudo);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite um número !");
                    }
                } else {

                }
                return false;
            });
        });

        return painel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pesquisa teste = new Pesquisa();
        teste.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objetivo e detectar o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> é melhor usar [`KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html):

```
pesquisa.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
             String conteudo = pesquisa.getText();
             if (!(conteudo.isEmpty())) {
                 resultado.setText("Resultado: " + conteudo);
             } else {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite um número !");
             }
        } else {

        }
    }

});
```

Leitura recomendada: [How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: Já agradeço pela otimização do código, mais, o que eu quero dizer, é que voce utiliza o enter pra pesquisa, ate ai tudo bem, porém, se o usuário der enter no campo, ele ele estiver  vazio, vai gerar erro, e se ele tentar fechar esse erro (mensagem de erro) clicando enter, ele vai entrar em loop, eu queria evitar esse loop, entende ?

Comment: @G.Araujo a solução da resposta acaba com o loop. Nao utilize cascata de eventos como fez a não ser que saiba as consequências disso. E uma das consequencias do seu código é justamente o loop. Se você precisa apenas validar a pesquisa vazia ao digitar enter, você não precisa adicionar evento de foco de teclado, como fez usando keyboardmanager, pois ao fechar o alerta, o foco volta pro componente, o que dispara esse evento novamente abrindo o alerta de novo, e assim sucessivamente. Na minha sugestão, só vai checar quando enter for pressionado e solto.